# How can i distribute items of listbox in two arrays in vb?

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am writing a program to read many lines from a textfile (line by line), each line contains 2 numbers separated by comma ",", first part is latitude and second is longitude. I am taking each line and storing it in a listbox.

I have a listbox in which each item includes two numbers (latitude and longitude) separated by comma "," (ex.: 12,64).
I want to create two array, first array containing latitudes and the second containing longitudes.

Comment: What is your question? I assume `lat` and `long` are `String`? What are `lat1` and `lat2`?

Comment: they are  also string

Comment: Then the only array I see is the `Value` array. What is your question?

Comment: i have to remove the first value and store it in lat1  and remove the last value and store in lat2 of value(0) .array

Comment: Isn't that what you already did? What values are we talking about? It would be helpful if you could edit your question to include a small example.

Comment: i have written above what i face the problem?   In lat1 ..i want to took all the numbers or values... except the last value. But what i write in the codes  this  removes the last character of every value. and in lat2 show the value except the first value ... i have find the distace between lat1 and lat2 for every step

Comment: TOM, just to be sure I got your question right:
You have a text file containing many lines, in each line you have numbers separated by comma, like this for example if the text file contains 2 lines:
1,68
2,121

You want for each line, to know how many numbers it contains? Or you want to know the difference between the last number and first number?

Comment: yes, In each line I have one latitide and longitude separated by comma

Comment: Please read my edited comment and let me know. Sorry I posted it before finishing by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should define appropriate data structures. Latitude values are usually numbers. So, a `Double()` seems appropriate. Then:

```
Dim lat1(ListBox1.Items.Count - 2) As Double
Dim lat2(ListBox1.Items.Count - 2) As Double
For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    Dim itemString = ListBox1.Items(i)
    Dim splitItemString = itemString.Split(","c)
    'Use Parse only if you're absolutely sure that this works.
    'Use TryParse otherwise
    Dim lat = Double.Parse(splitItemString(0))
    Dim lon = Double.Parse(splitItemString(1))

    'Now we can fill the arrays
    If i < ListBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then lat1(i) = lat
    If i > 0 Then lat2(i - 1) = lat
 Next
```

However, just calculating distances barely requires two arrays. Instead, you should fill a single array (maybe even with a reasonable `Struct` consisting of latitude and longitude values) and then:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To Coordinates.Count - 1
    'Calculate distance between Coordinates(i) and Coordinates(i + 1)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I got your original question right, but I hope these blocks would be helpful.
This code would redistribute your listbox's Items in 2 arrays of Double:

```
    Dim allLatitudes(0) As Double
    Dim allLongtitudes(0) As Double
    Dim counter As Integer

    For Each item In ListBox1.Items
        Dim tempstr = item.ToString

        Dim value = tempstr.Split(","c)
        Dim lat = Double.Parse(value(0)) ' to convert it to numeric
        Dim lon = Double.Parse(value(1)) ' to convert it to numeric

        ReDim Preserve allLatitudes(counter)
        allLatitudes(UBound(allLatitudes)) = lat

        ReDim Preserve allLongtitudes(counter)
        allLongtitudes(UBound(allLongtitudes)) = lon

        counter = counter + 1
    Next
```

In case you want to get for each item 2 arrays, one containing all values except last one, second containing all values except first one, than the code would be:

```
    For Each item In ListBox1.Items
        Dim tempstr = item.ToString

        Dim value = tempstr.Split(","c)
        Dim lat = value.Take(value.Length - 1).ToArray()
        Dim lon = value.Skip(1).ToArray()
    Next
```

Comment: before i got it . My question is to split lat into 2 array...so that i can find distance like  a-b , b-c, c-d ,  a,b,c are in one ...b,c,d are second

Comment: Dim dist As Double = Math.Sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.Sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + Math.Cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.Cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.Cos(deg2)    which i can use here to find distance

Comment: In this case... it  skips the  first and last character  of every value

Comment: humm.. no. assuming tempstr = "1,12,34", then I will have value containing {"1", "12", "34"}, lat will be an array containing {"1", "12"}, and lon will be an array containing {"12", "34"}

Comment: yes tempstr can be a single line from your file, didn't you say that a line is like "a,b,c"? line 1 is "a,b,c" line 2 is "d,e,f" ...

Comment: i have tried it before. i did not work ... i read it through a loop .. is there any other method??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79423/discussion-between-saleem-and-tom).